# Dataframe to dictionary like nested list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I am trying to create a nested dictionary starting from a data.frame.

```
dta <- data.frame(x = c('A','B','A','B'),
                  y = c('P','Q','Q','P'),
                  z = c(89,12,34,56)
                  ) |> print()
    #>   x y  z
    #> 1 A P 89
    #> 2 B Q 12
    #> 3 A Q 34
    #> 4 B P 56
```

The following is not what I am looking for.

```
  as.list(dta)
    #> $x
    #> [1] "A" "B" "A" "B"
    #> $y
    #> [1] "P" "Q" "Q" "P"
    #> $z
    #> [1] 89 12 34 56
```

What I am trying to do is to create a lookup table using `make_nested_list` such that
`nested_dta = make_nested_list(dta)` and `nested_dta['A']['P']` will output `89`.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66316828/r-dataframe-to-nested-list) is close but not useful for my case.
I am trying to do this in base R so that it is more readable. `dplyr` can do this but seems wordy `library(tidyvserse);dta %>% filter(x=='A',y=='P') %>% pull(z)`. There are other use cases that may benefit from the base R formulation. Is there is a better way to create the nested dictionary? Thank you.

Comment: You can get the same output in base R as `dplyr` - `with(dta, z[x=='A' & y=='P'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split` in `by`.

```
make_nested_list <- function(d) by(d, dta$x, \(b) split(b$z, b$y))
nested_dta <- make_nested_list(dta)
nested_dta[['A']][['P']]
# [1] 89
nested_dta$A$P
# [1] 89
```

Comment: Thanks. The generated list supports both `$` and `[[`. How would one define a general function that would take any number of columns and make a (multi)nested list

Comment: @Stat-R Good question, perhaps you might want to make examples of such possible lists, function usage, and output.

Answer (score 2):

You may define a custom function

```
dta <- data.frame(x = c('A','B','A','B'), y = c('P','Q','Q','P'), z = c(89,12,34,56) )

lt <- function(x, y, df = dta){
  return(df[df[1]==x & df[2] == y, 3])
}

lt('A', 'P')

[1] 89
```

Still if you want creating a nested list, a tidyverse option can be

```r
dta <- data.frame(x = c('A','B','A','B'), y = c('P','Q','Q','P'), z = c(89,12,34,56) )

library(tidyverse)
dta %>%
  split(.$x, drop = TRUE) %>%
  map(~ split(.x, .x$y, drop = T)) %>%
  map_depth(2, ~.x %>% pull(z)) -> nested_list

nested_list
#> $A
#> $A$P
#> [1] 89
#> 
#> $A$Q
#> [1] 34
#> 
#> 
#> $B
#> $B$P
#> [1] 56
#> 
#> $B$Q
#> [1] 12
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: May be save even more by `\(x, y,df=dta){
  return(df[df[1]==substitute(x) & df[2] == substitute(y), 3])
}`

Comment: Not thought in the direction of creating a function like what you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired nested list using `setNames` and `Map`.

```
nested_list <- Map(setNames, setNames(as.list(dta$z), dta$x), dta$y)
nested_list

#$A
# P 
#89 

#$B
# Q 
#12 

#$A
# Q 
#34 

#$B
# P 
#56
```

Check output -

```
nested_list[['A']][['P']]
#[1] 89

nested_list[['B']][['Q']]
#[1] 12
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, a less wordy approach to query a lookup table can be achieved using a *keyed data.table*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta, key = c("x", "y"))

dta[.("A", "P"), z]
```

> [1] 89